# How to echo user data using a second model

Tags: laravel-5

I want to display the name of a user alongside his notes. I have two models the user and the Notes Model. The Notes Model has the id of the user and the relationship is good.

How do I fetch the name of a user using their id in the view?

I have used plain php between the `<span>` tags `</span>`

```
@foreach($notes as $note)
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <span><strong><?php $userid=$note->user_id;
             $user = App\User::find($userid);
             $name = $user->name;
             echo $name;?>:::</strong></span>
            <span class="success">{{$note->note_title}}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-panel"> {!! html_entity_decode($note->note_body)!!}</div>
        </div>
        @endforeach
```

Am getting the correct name but I guess that's not the correct way in laravel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at my own question two years later and I cannot believe that was me, anyway its progress.

Actually that`s easy `{{$note->user->name}}`

Answer (score 0):

If your model relationships are configured correctly the user model doesn't need to be fetched in view.

You can get the users name through the one to many relationship.

Take a look here
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse